# Homomorphism between $S_4$ and non zero real numbers under multiplication

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-homomorphism

Let $S_4$ denote the symmetric group of 4 letters, and $\mathbb {R^*}$ be the multiplicative group of non-zero real numbers. If $f: S_4 \to \mathbb{R}^*$ is a homomorphism. Then the set 
$\{ x \in S_4 : f(x)=1\}$ has

1) atleast 12 elements

2) exactly 24 elements

3) atmost 12 elements

4) exactly 4 elements.

We know that $ ker(f)$ is a normal subgroup of $S_4$.

Comment: it could have $12$ elements, since $A_4$ is normal in $S_4$, and it could have $24$ elements; choice 1) is the only one compatible with that

Comment: Can you show that no element of $S_4$ is mapped to $2$?  What are the possible images of $f$?

Comment: HINT: How many elements in $\mathbb{R}$ have finite order?

Answer (score 1):

Since $|f(x)|$ must divide $24$, we have $f(x)=\pm1,\,\forall x$.  But $f(e)=1$.  Thus the order is at least $12$.  Note,  $f$ is $n$ to $1$, where $n=|\operatorname{ker}f|$, by the first isomorphism theorem.